# Retrieve count of orders by specific (each) date , example in Saturday has 20 orders in Sunday has 22 how can do it

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

```
Select
     ORDER_DATE as count_date,
     (select Count(ORDER_ID_TRN) as 'qty' from Orders)
from
     Orders
group by
     ORDER_DATE
```

Having `ORDER_DATE = '2019-12-14'`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group your data then aggregate functions like `count()` apply to each group and not the complete result set

```
Select
     ORDER_DATE as count_date,
     Count(ORDER_ID_TRN) as qty
from
     Orders
group by
     ORDER_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `count(*)` for counting orders.

```
Select
     ORDER_DATE as count_date,
     count(*)
from
     Orders
group by
     ORDER_DATE
```